# How to remove an attribute option in Magento?

Tags: magento, attributes, custom-attributes

For example, I want to delete an unnesesary option for a customer's entity "gender" attribute. How can I do this programmatically (not from admin panel)?

Answer (score -3):

you can disable this attribute from system > configuration > customer > customer options > name and address options

And you can change this programmatically like changing any other config value in Magento . You'll find the tutorial there http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-programmatically-change-magentos-core-config-data/

Comment: This has to do nothing whatsoever with core_config_data.